# System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file because it is already being used by another process.'

Tags: c#, .net

```
        public void AddPictureDialog_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {

            string PictureName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AddPictureDialog.FileName);
            string PicturePath = "../Pictures/" + PictureName + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AddPictureDialog.FileName) +
                Path.GetExtension(AddPictureDialog.FileName);

            File.Copy(AddPictureDialog.FileName, PicturePath);
            Database.Pictures.Add(new Picture(PicturePath));

            UpdateInterface();
        }
        
        public void UpdateInterfacePictures() 
        {
            ScrollBar_Pictures.Maximum = Database.Pictures.Count / 10;

            Panel[] panels = { panel_Picture_1, panel_Picture_2, panel_Picture_3, panel_Picture_4, panel_Picture_5, panel_Picture_6, panel_Picture_7, panel_Picture_8, panel_Picture_9, panel_Picture_10 };
            PictureBox[] pictureBoxes = { pictureBox_Picture_1, pictureBox_Picture_2, pictureBox_Picture_3, pictureBox_Picture_4, pictureBox_Picture_5, pictureBox_Picture_6, pictureBox_Picture_7, pictureBox_Picture_8, pictureBox_Picture_9, pictureBox_Picture_10 };
            Label[] labels = { label_Picture_1, label_Picture_2, label_Picture_3, label_Picture_4, label_Picture_5, label_Picture_6, label_Picture_7, label_Picture_8, label_Picture_9, label_Picture_10 };

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Panel panel = panels[i];
                PictureBox picture = pictureBoxes[i];
                Label label = labels[i];

                int index = i + (ScrollBar_Pictures.Value * 10);
                
                if (index < Database.Pictures.Count)
                {
                    panel.Visible = true;
                    picture.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Database.Pictures[index].Path_);
                    label.Text = Database.Pictures[index].Name;
                }
                else
                    panel.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        
        public void UpdateInterface()
        {
            pictureBox_Picture.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Database.Pictures[PictureIndex].Path_);
        }


        public void button_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete " + Database.Pictures[PictureIndex].Name,
                "Moments Remember", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Database.Pictures.Remove(Database.Pictures[PictureIndex]);
                Close();            
            }
        }
        
        public void DeleteRemovedPictures()
        {
            string[] PicturesPath = Directory.GetFiles("../Pictures/");

            for (int i = 0; i < PicturesPath.Length; i++)
                if (!Pictures.Contains(new Picture(PicturesPath[i])))
                    File.Delete(PicturesPath[i]);
        }
```

Hey there,

I'm currently working on a project involving picture management, and I've encountered some issues that I could use some assistance with.

Below is a snippet of the code I'm working with.

The functionality I'm trying to achieve involves adding pictures, updating the interface to display these pictures, and allowing users to delete them.

However, I'm experiencing some difficulties with:

```
File.Delete(PicturesPath[i]);
```

I'm particularly stuck on System.IO.IOException, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any insights or guidance you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Best regards.

Comment: see my answer, did I used it wrong?

Comment: All the solutions in the duplicate load the file bytes in memory and create `Image` instances from the bytes. A `MemoryStream` is nothing more than a wrapper over a `byte[]` buffer

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the file you are trying to access, in your case delete, is currently open in another thread so it cannot be modified/deleted until you close the file or the thread.

Instead of creating an array of picture paths in your delete, move it to a global list of paths that you can always access. This should allow you to add/delete from that list without having to create a new Picture object every time you want to check if it already exists.